# A triangle with integral sides has a perimeter of $15$. How many such triangles are possible?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

I know this formula that goes like this :-
If the perimeter of the triangle is given, then the number of integral-sided triangles possible is $\frac{p^2}{48}$ where $p$ is the perimeter of the given triangle and its value is even or $\frac{(p+3)^2}{48}$ if the perimeter value is odd.

Perimeter given $= 15$ ==> Odd Value

As per the formula, the value comes out to be $6.75$ but here I am confused as to what should be the answer. It's definitely not $6.75$. It's either going to be $6$ or $7$ but how to decide on that? Please help!!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Perhaps the formula is wrong.  It clearly does not give the right answer when $p=3$ or $4$ where I would have thought the answers would be $1$ and $1$

Comment: Maybe we have to take the ceiling function? Idk

Comment: You can find a recursive formula in [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980033/combinatorics-question-involving-incongruent-integral-sided-triangles). And I tested that rounding of your formula to integer give the same result. I think you can use induction to prove it.

Comment: The answer has been given as 7 but since I got 6.75, I thought definitely there's gonna be 6 triangles, so I wrote 6 as the answer.